# RestKit and Pull to Refresh

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, restkit

Does Restkit support the Pull To refresh gesture for UITableViews? If so, where can I find examples on how to use it and get it working?

I've been looking at SVPullToRefresh but seems to not be working properly for me. I'm probably hooking it up wrong. Is there an example of SVPullToRefresh for RestKit or any other webservice? I am a newbie to Objective-C so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So figured it out.

I'll explain it very briefly in case someone else is looking for an answer to this.

I ended up using [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) with RestKit for it.

Basically hooked up the pullToRefresh and InfiniteScroll methods to the ObjectLoader Delegate in the View Controller's .m file.

For Infinite Scroll, you'll need to add another method that figures out the offset and then adds the new data to your old data's array. Then just insert it into the table.